# What are the drawbacks of Rebuild Reporting Database?

Tags: sitecore-client, reporting

I tried to rebuild reporting database but it goes on for indefinite time.
In the Rebuild Reporting database page it's showing

> **(Waiting to receive to data status)**

According to a blog, I need to copy following marketing definition tables from the primary to the secondary reporting database:

1. CampaignActivityDefinitions
2. GoalDefinitions
3. OutcomeDefinitions
4. MarketingAssetDefinitions
5. Taxonomy_TaxonEntity
6. Taxonomy_TaxonEntityFieldDefinition
7. Taxonomy_TaxonEntityFieldValue

Do I need to copy any other tables or are there any other ways to resolve the error?

And are there any drawbacks if I follow these steps.

Are there any possible errors I face during production?

Answer (score 4):

I've followed this process a number of times and haven't hit any ongoing issues yet.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

The (Waiting to receive to data status) message is displayed for as long as the timer setting is set in the TimeToClearStorage value in Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config

Be warned, copying the data can take some time if your Analytics database has been in use for some time. You should set the TimeToClearStorage value to an value that allows the manual transfer of data.

I've used the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to transfer data previously (Right click the DB, Tasks > Export Data ...

You could write a script but I've found the built in tools to do the trick just fine.

I've found it useful to leave the secondary Reporting database instance in place after the rebuild, it's likely you'll need it again in the future.

Comment: Hello Ben what value did you set in TimeToClearStorage for manual data transfer?

Comment: All depends on how much data there is to transfer. I started with 10 mins initially but my db's were pretty much empty so I reduced to 1 min and had no problems. If your tables contain data, it's worth running an export as a test and checking how long the transfer takes. Then you can set the value to something realistic